# Fragment in Custom View

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, custom-attributes

I'm writing the `View` that will be responsible for capturing the picture and previewing it.
I'm implementing it using `Fragment`, as long as I need to use `startActivityForResult()`.

It does what I want but after capturing I need to get this `Image` in my `CustomImageView` `class` but **My Problem** is that I can't get this `Fragment` from the `View` in my `Custom View`.

Here's the code:

**CustomImageView:**

```
public class CustomImageView extends LinearLayout {
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private View view;
  private CustomFragment frag;

  public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initViews();
  }

  private void initViews(){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_imageview, this, true);

    //  Get Fragment Here . . . .
  }
```

}

**view_imageView** (CustomImageView xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.fragments.CustomFragment"
        custom:viewParameter="eg ari ra"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I need to get `Fragment` in `initViews()` (as I commented above) but I don't know how. 
Please Share your ideas.

Please help me if you can. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried `frag = Fragment.instantiate(getContext(), CustomFragment.class.getName(), null);`

Comment: if i use Fragment.instantiate then how can i add it to my View ?

Comment: Oh you already have this fragment inside your layout, sorry. You just need to do `frag = (CustomFragment)getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);` But for this you need `Activity`'s reference.

Comment: that's why i'm asking this question :))) I know that I need activity's reference. I want to know if there's any way to have my custom view well encapsulated.

Comment: have you got any solution ? Ia m in same situation

Answer (score -1):

have u tried... the following:

### First try to get the FragmentManager

FragmentManager manager  = ((Activity context).getFragmentManager();
or ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

Fragment fragment = manager.getFragmentById("fragment");